# SUDS loosing SOAP part of body

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm sending a SOAP request to update some entity. When I create (instead of update) nearly same thing, everything works fine. I've tracked logging from Client and Transport and finally it gave me a clue. It looks like this:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://webservices.autotask.net/ATServices/1.5/atws.asmx)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:update>
    <ns0:Entities xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ns0:Entity xsi:type="ns0:Ticket">
        <ns0:id>123</ns0:id>
        <ns0:UserDefinedFields xsi:type="xsd:string"></ns0:UserDefinedFields>
        <ns0:AccountID xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:AccountID>
        <ns0:AllocationCodeID xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:AllocationCodeID>
        <ns0:CompletedDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 14:47:02</ns0:CompletedDate>
        <ns0:CreateDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 04:08:02.000203</ns0:CreateDate>
        <ns0:CreatorResourceID xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:CreatorResourceID>
        <ns0:Description xsi:type="xsd:string"></ns0:Description>
        <ns0:DueDateTime xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-05 09:36:00</ns0:DueDateTime>
        <ns0:EstimatedHours xsi:type="xsd:string">0.0</ns0:EstimatedHours>
        <ns0:IssueType xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:IssueType>
        <ns0:LastActivityDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 14:47:04.000157</ns0:LastActivityDate>
        <ns0:Priority xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:Priority>
        <ns0:QueueID xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:QueueID>
        <ns0:Status xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:Status>
        <ns0:SubIssueType xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:SubIssueType>
        <ns0:TicketNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">123</ns0:TicketNumber>
        <ns0:Title xsi:type="xsd:string">foo</ns0:Title>
        <ns0:FirstResponseDateTime xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 14:47:02.000427</ns0:FirstResponseDateTime>
        <ns0:ResolutionPlanDateTime xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 14:47:02.000427</ns0:ResolutionPlanDateTime>
        <ns0:ResolvedDateTime xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-04 14:47:02.000427</ns0:ResolvedDateTime>
        <ns0:Resolution xsi:type="xsd:string"></ns0:Resolution>
    </ns0:Entity>
  </ns0:Entities>
</ns0:update>
</ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/update"';, 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL:https://webservices.autotask.net/ATServices/1.5/atws.asmx
HEADERS: {'Soapaction': u'"http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/update"', 'SOAPAction': u'"http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/update"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Basic YXV0b21hdGlhQGFyY2VzLm5ldDp5dWYkOWFyN2VQaDY='}
MESSAGE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:update>
    <Entities/>
  </ns0:update>
</ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And with this I get an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Anyone has any idea, what happens with this SOAP request, that it looses it's whole Entity body and proceed an empty message? Is it a problem with suds, server, code, me?

Thanks for any little help in understing what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, so I can finally close it.

If anyone will be interested, the problem was solved. There is a bug in suds.sx reported [here](http://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/359). As the SOAP request was edited with this one, the request which I sent was empty. To correct it, I had to delete the sx part and change it with a MessagePlugin. If anyone will be interested - write here.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you fix the issue ? I am also facing the same issue. My Soap body is empty.